# Getting this error for last 3 days "Timeout while fetching the main resource."

Tags: performance, page-speed, google-pagespeed

I am getting "Timeout while fetching the main resource." error for one my site for last 3 days.

[Check here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftoptalent.com.au%2F)

speed insight tool shows erratic screen shot of site. sometimes show partially loaded mobile version and sometimes partially loaded desktop view.

The error does not appear when checked with https, but screen shots (both mobile and desktop) are wierd.

I am getting this error for last 3 days.

I checked in google webmaster tools and tried fetch as google. There too site does not appear as it appears on browser.

I check robots.txt and htaccess. But did not find anything.

Can anybody help?

Comment: I am 100% sure that this is a bug in google' speed insight tool because rest all the speed tools (pingdom, gtmetrix and webpagetest.org) showing correct design of the site.

Comment: Whatever the problem was, it appears to be resolved now.  I just tried your link and it seems to work.

Comment: I'm closing this question because it appears to have been a temporary problem that is now resolved without getting an answer here.